# Current macro on user space

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, user-mode-linux

Is that possible to access the current struct from user-mode? I have read that on kernel mode the Current macro gives a pointer to the current  task_struct. Is there a way to access this struct from user mode?

Edit:

I mean for reading.
I know we can read /dev/mem, the question is, is there a way to get to the the task_struct of the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `task_struct` is internal kernel structure not exposed to user space because if one can get access to "own" thread structure then one can get access to many other internal kernel structures like all task structures for current session (via pid lists).

Comment: Internal kernel data placed in kernel memory area and not allowed even for reading from user space.

Comment: OK. Thank. What about setting exception handler that will run on kernel mode, and causing that exception? Is it possible?